# handling wars in multiplayer browser game

Tags: javascript, html5, php, node.js, three.js

I'm building a browser game about countries, cities, the user control his city, building it upgrading it, can fight other cities in the same country, elections and war between countries, peace, trade agreements, and many many more cool stuff.
The game is in full size window, all of the website will be dynamic and will be playable in 1 page, and won't redirect to any other page.

i'm using php, javascript (jquery), css, html at work, so I'm very friendly with those languages.

I have few questions about developing this kind of a game:

1. I have chose node.js for the back-end programing, because as of my understanding it's fast, and will do the best job for my game, i chose node because its made for handling many call at the same time, but the only place I really need it is in wars between countries and cities, where a lot of people can participate in one battle.
   Should i use php in rest of my website, for login, register, elections and use ajax, or stick with node.js for all of the back-end stuff, and why?
   or even use other language that can suit me better?
2. The big question is my front-end, the majority of my website can be done with simple js and other small libraries, for drag and drop, cool effects and such, but my problems is as the above, the wars. 
   The wars will be fought with max of 20 users in one window (battle), the idea of the battle is like the game LoL (league of legends), where the user is the hero, 10 heroes fight againsts 10 heroes, so it must be in real time, 3d and third person camera, all of the movement and attacks will be with the use of the mouse.
   I have no idea in programing 3d objects, i was looking into few js libraries and HTML5, like babylonjs, Three.js, playcanvas, the best i saw and i think that might suit me is playcanvas, but i'm afraid putting it all in one language just to find out that it can't be done with it.
   Does playcanvas suits my website, or should i take a look into any other plugin?

Comment: I don't think this question is appropriate for this forum. Everyone will give a different answer to 'what language should I use for X' because there is no clear cut answer. You should do some more research on your own for what languages and design practices fit your needs and then come back and ask more specific questions related to game development. This is one half a web development question anyway and this is not a web development forum. Best of luck!

Comment: We'll, its a forum for games development, and the question is if playcanvas the right language to use for the things i need in my game, i don't ask what language i need to use, i'm asking if i should combine 2 languages in my website or stick to one in the back-end, and why one is better then the other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost too many questions in one post, and a little too non-specific for stackoverflow, but I'll try to answer as best as I can:

1. As you've correctly discerned, you'll at least need a node.js server for the wars. Additionally, that node.js server might profit from not having to do anything other than wars. In other words: Even if you choose to use nodejs for the rest of your site, running 2 seperate nodejs servers (or at least processes) possibly even on different machines could help stability. I would probably do a node.js server for the main game and then have it spawn a seperate process for every war.
2. I think it's plausible to do everything in nodejs, a single dynamic page is definitely a better fit for javascript than php, which tends to shine for multi-page websites. Having the main game on a node.js server will also make it easier for it to communicate with the wars server (or process, if you decide to take that route). For client-server communication use websockets, or socket.io if you prefer to use a library instead of raw websockets.
3. I usually avoid using too many libraries unnecessarily, so going with just one library, or even writing your engine from scratch, is how I would do it. Also, make sure you use something that utilizes WebGL if you want 3D animation that runs well. Unfortunately I can't give you advice on any of the libraries you listed, as I have used none of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick comment, i think the question will be blocked soon, as i see no one likes the question ><, but i'll wait to see maybe some one have used the libraries i mentioned, and can give a full detailed answer. Thanks again

Comment: @user3052629 If you like my answer, make sure to accept it. This let's others know that it has been answered. As for the libraries, I suggest looking for reviews/demos of them and making a decision based on that.